# How to set Scope in Application Insight for Azure Function?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-application-insights

When I use Application Insight in an Azure Function it looks like

```cs
using (_logger.BeginScope("MyLog")) 
{
 _logger.LogInformation("Test");
}
```

has no effects, i.e. the log appears in Application Insight but it doens't contains any scope in customDimensions.
The same exact code works fine in a web api project.

**UPDATE:**

If I try to set the scope with

```cs
using (_logger.BeginScope(new Dictionary<string, object> { ["Scope"] = "MyLog" }))
{
 _logger.LogInformation("Test");
}
```

I can see the scope set in customDimensions but the name is: **prop__Scope** instead of just **Scope**

Is this an undocumented behaviour or am I missing something?

Comment: I wonder if Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights supports scoping.

^ This is supported https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger#logging-scopes

Comment: in Azure Functions, you don't need to install even Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.

Comment: You're right @cijothomas Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights is not needed, question edited.

Answer (score 1):

I can see the scope set in customDimensions but the name is: prop__Scope instead of just Scope

> "The prop__ prefix is added to ensure there are no collisions between
> fields the runtime adds and fields your function code adds."

This is the documented behavior for Azure Functions. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library?tabs=v2%2Ccmd#structured-logging

Comment: Thanks @cijothomas I still wonder why _logger.BeginScope("MyLog") doesn't work in Function and feel that it is fine to prefix prop__ for structured logging but not for scoping (and in non function prj scoping has no prefix)

Comment: Functions uses special integration with ApplicationInsights, and chose to add prefix.

Comment: I do not know why logger.BeginScope("MyLog") does not work. Maybe the functions implementation is expecting IReadOnlyList<KeyValuePair<string, object>> as scope, and nothing else.

Comment: @cijothomas I have a case like, using (_logger.BeginScope(scope)), where the scope is of dictionary<string, object> type. But, I do not see them in Application Insights. Any idea?